# How to handle multiple schemes/targets in one iOS app when migrating from Crashlytics to Firebase?

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I am currently in the process of moving my apps from Crashlytics to Firebase Crashlytics as per Fabric's guidelines.

My scenario is that in my app, I have four different schemes (Four targets) with four different bundle identifiers which correspond to my dev, internal-qa, client-qa and live servers.

I created four different projects for the four "Apps" like I did in Fabric Crashlytics.

Now the next step would have been adding the "GoogleService-Info.plist" as generated by Firebase in my project. All four Firebase Projects for my four apps (Which are in fact different schemes of the same App) generated a plist with the same name. It currently looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>AD_UNIT_ID_FOR_BANNER_TEST</key>
    <string>XXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>AD_UNIT_ID_FOR_INTERSTITIAL_TEST</key>
    <string>XXXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>XXXXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>REVERSED_CLIENT_ID</key>
    <string>XXXXX</string>
    <key>API_KEY</key>
    <string>XXXXXX</string>
    <key>GCM_SENDER_ID</key>
    <string>XXXXXXX</string>
    <key>PLIST_VERSION</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>BUNDLE_ID</key>
    <string>[MY SCHEME BUNDLE ID]</string>
    <key>PROJECT_ID</key>
    <string>[MY PROJECT ID]</string>
    <key>STORAGE_BUCKET</key>
    <string>XXXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>IS_ADS_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>IS_ANALYTICS_ENABLED</key>
    <false></false>
    <key>IS_APPINVITE_ENABLED</key>
    <false></false>
    <key>IS_GCM_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>IS_SIGNIN_ENABLED</key>
    <true></true>
    <key>GOOGLE_APP_ID</key>
    <string>XXXXXXXXX</string>
    <key>DATABASE_URL</key>
    <string>XXXXXXXXXXX</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

How do I go about it? Just add all four in my project with different names? Or just add all four but modify the target membership of each? The bundle ids, app keys inside the plists are different after all. How are we supposed to handle the case of multiple schemes in one iOS App?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is how I handled the same thing in my project. I kept 4 GoogleService-Info.Plist file with different name and kept them in folder in my project. But make sure, you are not adding the same in project navigator.(So, these 4 files will reside in my project folder, but not in my project. In short, it will not going to be compiled automatically.)

Now, you have to add run script in each 4 targets for programmatically changing name of each plist file to required name and then adding it to bundle to programmatically, so that only single out of 4 file, with required name going to be added.

Here is how to do above step.

1. Select `Target1`(whatever is your target name)
2. Now, Select 'Build Phases' in top available tabs.
3. Here, you will see the '+' button at left top corner. Click on it.
4. There will be multiple option, now select `New Run Script Phase` from there. It will add one new Run Script in your list with name `Run Script`. If you want, then you can change name of it by double clicking the name. In my case i kept name `RunScriptForGooglePlist`.
5. There will be `Shell` with value `/bin/sh`. And just below that, there will be textview, where you have to write the following code. Make sure that, you are changing neccessary name changes of files, based on your names of plist files.

Here, is the code for the same.

```
PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS="${PROJECT_DIR}/MyProjectFolder/GooglePlists"

cp -r "$PATH_TO_GOOGLE_PLISTS/GoogleService-Info-dev.plist" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/GoogleService-Info.plist"
```

Here, first line of code, I am taking path of folder where all 4 google plist file were kept with 4 different names.

And, In second line, I am copying this file to new location, which is my application's app bundle, with required name.(As I mentioned already at top, as we are not adding these all 4 files in bundle, so they are not going to be compiled. And, the app bundle will not have this file. In this script, you are adding this required file to its required location with the name that google/firebase's sdk required).

You have to repeat above, same procedure for all 4 targets, and in second line of above code, just make name change as required for given target.

If you dont get any of above step OR it is still not working, then just comment, I will surely help you out.

Comment: Thanks for the help Mehul. I put the script in and named it "Run Firebase Script", It throws this error on build: `Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code`.  Any ideas? It says it might a syntax error with ';;'. Are the semi colons required? If I remove them, the build succeeds.

Comment: Yeah it works if you take out the semi colons. Thanks

Comment: oh sorry.. thats mistake