# Flutter: Upload dsym symbols to Firebase crashlytics with flavors

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, crashlytics

I want to upload dsym symbols from Flutter app with multiple **flavors**. Each GoogleService-Info is places inside config/flavor_name folder. What script should I add to "Build Phases" to upload dsym to Firebase Crashlytics?

Try script from another thread but it seems it doesn't work

Comment: Could you provide more info about your current configuration? How is your Flutter project structured? Do you have different targets in the iOS project? What is the current run script you are using? How are you building the app for the different targets/flavors?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to handle multiple schemes/targets in one iOS app when migrating from Crashlytics to Firebase?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53557368/how-to-handle-multiple-schemes-targets-in-one-ios-app-when-migrating-from-crashl)

Answer (score 7):

Here is a better script. Instead of cat and grep, it uses PlistBuddy, a built-in Mac tool. Also, don't forget step 5. from here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-deobfuscated-reports?platform=flutter

```bash
environment="default"

# Get environment name
if [[ $CONFIGURATION =~ -([^-]*)$ ]]; then
environment=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi

echo $environment

# Name and path of the resource we're reading
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE=${PROJECT_DIR}/config/${environment}/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}

# Make sure GoogleService-Info.plist exists
if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE ]
then
echo "No GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
exit 1
fi

# Get app id
APP_ID=$(/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :GOOGLE_APP_ID" "${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE}")

echo $APP_ID

$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase --validate -ai ${APP_ID}
$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase -ai ${APP_ID}
```

Comment: This assumes we have GoogleService-Info.plist files. Is there also a method for dart-only initialization without GoogleService-Info.plist files?

Comment: One way to do it would be to use a script that copies the correct file based on the flavor to the destination before the build.

Comment: yes but how do you identify the correct flavor? Afaik there is no way to get the scheme in the XCode build phase

Comment: Can you run the script in the same place as the script above? The flavor name should be same as the "environment" variable in this script.

Answer (score 2):

I found a script

```
environment="default"

if [[ $CONFIGURATION =~ -([^-]*)$ ]]; then
environment=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
fi

GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST=GoogleService-Info.plist
GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE=${PROJECT_DIR}/config/${environment}/${GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_PLIST}

if [ ! -f $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE ]
then
echo "No GoogleService-Info.plist found. Please ensure it's in the proper directory."
exit 1
fi

google_app_id=$(cat $GOOGLESERVICE_INFO_FILE | grep -oEi '\d:\d*?:ios:[[:alnum:]]*')

echo $google_app_id

$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase --validate -ai $google_app_id
$PODS_ROOT/FirebaseCrashlytics/upload-symbols --build-phase  -ai $google_app_id
```

Comment: This is exactly what I’m looking for, the google_app_id that follows flavor (not the hardcoded one that writen in documentation). Thank You