# Firebase dSYM Missing Issue - Multiple Falvors

Tags: flutter, xcode, firebase, cannot-find-symbol, dsym

I'm encountering an issue with Firebase in my project, specifically related to a missing dSYM file. I've tried multiple setups with Xcode for setting up with different flavors. , but I'm still stuck.

- Xcode version: Latest

I've checked my Firebase configuration, and everything seems to be in order. However, when releasing the development version there seems to be a missing dSYM only on dev where production is working fine, I get an error related to a missing dSYM file.

Error message:
Missing dSYM file for Firebase

I tried using scripts found in this community.

[Flutter: Upload dsym symbols to Firebase crashlytics with flavors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75302880/flutter-upload-dsym-symbols-to-firebase-crashlytics-with-flavors)

https://medium.com/@animeshjain/build-flavors-in-flutter-android-and-ios-with-different-firebase-projects-per-flavor-27c5c5dac10b

None of the above is working also I see

Note:
firebase*app*id_file.json in the root of the iOS folder with production credentials of firebase.

Is there a way to modify firebase*app*id_file.json file with multiple flavors?
Credentials are removed for security reasons.

```
{
  "file_generated_by": "FlutterFire CLI",
  "purpose": "FirebaseAppID & ProjectID for this Firebase app in this directory",
  "GOOGLE_APP_ID": "APP_ID_HERE",
  "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID": "FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID",
  "GCM_SENDER_ID": "GCM_SENDER_ID"
}
```